# Mysql parent child tables reducing database calls or merge in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, database-design

If I had 2 tables, say blog_category and blog, each "blog" can belong in a particular category only so a 1-1  relationship based on a key called "blog_category_id".

Now in my code I would do something like:

```
//Loop through categories such as 
foreach($categories as $cat):
//then for each category create an array of all its posts
$posts = $cat->getPosts(); // This would be another DB call to get all posts for the cat
//do stuff with posts
endforeach;
```

Now to me this seems like it could end up quite expensive in terms of DB calls depending on the size of $categories. Would this still be the best solution to do this? Or would I be able to do something in the code and first retrieve all the categories, then retrieve all the blogs and map them to their corresponding category via the id somehow? This would in theory be only 2 calls to the DB, now size wise the result set for call 2 (the blogs) would definitely be larger, but would the actual DB call be as expensive?

I would normally go for the first option, but I'm just wondering if there would be a better way of approaching this or is it more likely that the extra processing in PHP would be more costly in terms of performance? Also specifically from an MVC perspective, if the model returns the categories, but it should also return the corresponding blogs for that category, I'm not sure how best to structure this, from my understanding, shouldn't the model return all the data required for the view?

Or would I be better off selecting all categories and blogs using inner joins in the first query and create the output I need of this? Perhaps by using a multi-dimensional array?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple SQL query to get all categories and posts like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
JOIN categories c ON c.id = p.blog_category_id
ORDER BY c.category_name ASC,
         p.posted_date DESC
```

Then when you loop over the returned records assign the current category id to a variable, which you can use to compare against the next records category. If the category is different then print the category title before printing the record. It is important to note that for this to work you need to get the posts ordered by category first and then post so that all posts in the same category are together.

So for example:

```
$category_id = null;
foreach($posts as $post) {
    if($post['blog_category_id'] != $category_id) {
        $category_id = $post['blog_category_id'];
        echo '<h2>' . $post['category_name'] . '</h2>';
    }
    echo '<h3>' . $post['post_title'] . '</h3>';
    echo $post['blog_content'];
}
```

**Note:** as you have not posted up the schema of these two tables I have had to make up column names that are similar to what I would expect to see in code like this. So the code above will not work with your code without some adjustments to account for this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I know how to do the join, but specifically I was looking for advice on what the best way to do this using an MVC structure should be balanced against what's best performance wise

Comment: Well MVC doesn't really have any affect on this code here. MVC is an overall structure and does not dictate database design. The 'M' in MVC might not even be talking to a DB, but could be using an API etc. I have updated my answer to include template code as well.

Comment: hi, thanks again for the reply, I was just using pseudo code to try and simplify the example to explain what I wanted. I knew it wouldn't really dictate the DB design, but it was more about how to structure the code and whether or not there were any performance benefits depending on the way I did it (or if this had an effect on how an MVC project should be structure). Thanks for filling out your answer more, I'm new to MVC and haven't really found an in-depth tutorial on how to structure, mainly tutorials showing sample structures. I'll have a play around and update the question

Comment: The best example of MVC I know of is http://Agavi.org, but it is very heavy going for a beginner.

Comment: Cheers, I'll take a look. I'm used to coding in a variety of languages but it's just the structure to begin with. I've briefly played with Yii but none of the other big players like Zend etc. I wanted to get a graps of the concepts fully before diving in and just repeating what I see elsewhere without understanding it

Answer (score 1):

The best solution depends on what you are going to do with data.

**Lazy loading**

Load data when you need it. It's a good solution when you have, for instance, 20 categories and you load posts for only 2 of them. However, if you need to load posts for all of them it won't be efficient at all... It's called a n+1 queries (and it's really bad).

**Eager loading**

On the other hand, if you have to access to almost all of your posts, you should do an eager loading.

```
-- Load all your data in a query
SELECT *
FROM categories c
INNER JOIN posts p ON c.id = p.category_id;

// Basic example in JSON of how to format your result 
{
   'cat1': ['post1', 'post2'],
   'cat2': ['post5', 'post4', 'post5'],
   ...
}
```

**What to do?**

In your case I would say an eager loading because you load everything in a loop. But if you don't access to the most of your data, you should re-design your model to perform a lazy loading in such a way that the SQL query to load posts for a specific category is actually performed when a view try to access them.

What do you think?